# How to load custom collection with addfieldfilter and also get the total number of records?

Tags: magento2

I have custom collection in page. I need to get the total count and also need to set the query according to pagesize. How to return the total count and results of collection.

```
$custom_collection = $this->modelfactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('adf',array('eq'=>$%vendo))->setpagsize($pagelimit)->load();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :**

```
$vendo = 'test';
$pagelimit = 10;
$custom_collection = $this->modelfactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('adf',array('eq'=> $vendo))->setpagsize($pagelimit)->load();
```

Comment: How to get the total number of records

Comment: can you try this : $custom_collection = $this->modelfactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('adf',array('eq'=> $vendo));
echo $custom_collection->getSize(); exit